# Unable to import asynccontextmanager from contextlib

Tags: python

I'm new to python, i'm getting error when executing command. `python3 -m app`. Please Help me to fix this thanks.

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
ImportError: cannot import name 'asynccontextmanager'
```

Comment: @Equinox Please provide an answer based on your comment, so that this question doesn't keep popping up without one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Python version >= 3.7, then use

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
```

Otherwise, for Python versions < 3.7, use

```
from async_generator import asynccontextmanager
```